# Lightning message service vs platform events vs pubsub

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, platform-event, pubsublwc

Are they diffrerent or same? I just started knowing this technology and wanted to know if it is enough to learn only one of it

Answer (score 8):

They are different. Let's see how:-

1. Use Lightning message service to communicate across the DOM between
   Visualforce pages, Aura components, and Lightning web components,
   including components in a pop-out utility bar.
2. Use platform events to connect business processes in Salesforce and
   external sources through the exchange of real-time event data.
3. It means you can use Lightning Message service only in Vf pages and
   lightning components whereas platform events can be used with Apex,
   triggers, Lightning Flows, process builders and external systems.
4. Lightning Message Service is a front-end service that works in
   client-side user interfaces, which would include popped out utility
   bar item windows and parent/child iFrame windows (primarily
   Visualforce). All interactions have to originate from the same
   Lightning Experience application instance — i.e. same browser tab.
5. A lot of things can be done using platform events which cannot be done using Lightning message service. For example, watch this video on [Overcome Salesforce Governor Limits Using Platform Events](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUUpgz-_x34&t=780s)

Read about them more here:-

- [Communicate Across the DOM with Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel)
- [Platform Events Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm)

Comment: Can i refrain using pub sub and just always use lightning message service when working on lightning component communication?

Comment: pubsub was never the right solution. Pubsub was restricted to one page whereas message service will work across the pages

Comment: When you say across pages, Do you mean Lightning page with two different VF pages? What are other scenarios that come under across pages functionality?

Comment: If we have 2 users working at the same time with our application, would they be able "get" LMS messages of each other? E.g. first one adds new contact to the list, and in browser of the second user "list component" is refreshed to show newly added contact? Or is all this LMS thing works only in scope of "one browser"?